# Silverlight: Dependency property loses value when control is navigated away from

Tags: silverlight, binding, dependency-properties

I have a custom control that has two dependency properties. They are set as such:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ValueBindingProperty As DependencyProperty = _
DependencyProperty.Register("ValueBinding", GetType(String), GetType(HomePageControl), New PropertyMetadata(String.Empty))

Public Property ValueBinding As String
        Get
            Return DirectCast(Me.GetValue(HomePageControl.ValueBindingProperty), String)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.SetValue(HomePageControl.ValueBindingProperty, value)
        End Set
End Property
```

I assess them in the PropertyChangedCallback of another DP like this:

```
Dim hpc As HomePageControl = DirectCast(d, HomePageControl)
Dim valueBindingString as String = hpc.ValueBinding
```

And then I use it where I need it.

The value is there the first time that the page is loaded and the control is loaded. Once I navigate away from the page - using Silverlight navigation loading a new "view" into the frame - the value disappears and when I go back to the page/view that the control is on the value equals the default value instead of what it is set to in the xaml. What happened to the value?

I have other DP that are strings that remain set. As far as I can tell these two are set the same as the others. Why would these lose their value when the others don't?

Answer (score 1):

When navigation occurs, Silverlight removes the old page from the tree and adds a new one which has just been created. Therefore, when you navigate to a `URI` and come back, you get a new control which is in its default state.

You should store the state of the controls somewhere aside from them. It may be an in-memory object or a server-side database table. The choice depends on your requirements. Probably, the best and a universal approach is applying the MVVM pattern.